# Why my maven package triggered by Jenkins failed but can be success if I manually execute it?

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

I have a jenkins job which tend to build my java application using maven, but it always gets failure  during the compile phase.

```
[[1;34mINFO[m] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[[1;34mINFO[m] Compiling 550 source files to /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/test/target/classes
[[1;34mINFO[m] [1m------------------------------------------------------------------------[m
[[1;34mINFO[m] [1;31mBUILD FAILURE[m
[[1;34mINFO[m] [1m------------------------------------------------------------------------[m
[[1;34mINFO[m] Total time: 9.575 s
[[1;34mINFO[m] Finished at: 2017-12-02T07:47:47+08:00
[[1;34mINFO[m] Final Memory: 24M/346M
[[1;34mINFO[m] [1m------------------------------------------------------------------------[m
[[1;33mWARNING[m] The requested profile "nexus" could not be activated because it does not exist.
[[1;31mERROR[m] Failed to execute goal [32morg.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile[m [1m(default-compile)[m on project [36mtest[m: [1;31mCompilation failure[m -> [1m[Help 1][m
[[1;31mERROR[m]
```

I find and copied the below command in the Jenkins job's console output(on the webpage).

```
/opt/apache-maven-3.5.0/bin/mvn -f pom.xml -s /var/lib/jenkins/test-maven-setting/setting.xml -gs /var/lib/jenkins/test-maven-setting/setting.xml -Dmaven.repo.local=/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/test/.repository clean package
```

Then I switched to the jenkins user in the Linux console and go to the job's workspace directory and tried to manually execute the above commands I copied.

but it success!

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 20.994 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-12-02T07:50:17+08:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 35M/298M
```

so it's very strange, same commands, same user, same directory, but it can success when I execute it manually while fail when Jenkins build the job. Does anyone know what's the problem that Jenkins job failed?

here I retested the maven plugin and pasted some screenshots.
[image: Maven Configuration]

[image: Maven installations]

[image: The maven plugin setting in the Jenkins job]

[image: Error output]

Answer (score 0):

You as using "use default maven settings" option in invoke-maven-targets.

select option for "settings file in filesystem" for both default and global

Comment: setting.xml location was specified in the "Invoke-top-level-maven-targets" plugin advanced setting. so I think the problem is not this. Further to avoid any misconfiguration in plugin, I write the maven command directly in the Shell without using maven plugin, in the command I specified the setting.xlm location, but Jenkins will fail too, but if I ran that in Linux console it will success.

Comment: how about your maven. have you set it up in jenkins

Comment: maven is installed in the build server where the Jenkins also reside there. I installed the maven plugin in the Jenkins.

Comment: I think the application can be build either by maven plugin and by running the maven command in the execute shell in Jenkins without specific maven plugin.

Comment: why don't you try with maven plugin. you don't have to give all these parameters and it will be easier to find the cause

Comment: yes, I was going to troubleshoot so I switched from maven plugin to shell commands as the shell commands can be successfully executed by me manually. Let me change back to maven plugin and set it again.

Comment: I specified the setting.xml location as you suggested, but the job still failed, :(  Is it possible for you do remote assist?

Comment: can you share more info regarding your setup and job. maybe some images if possible

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160322/discussion-between-user1744416-and-prasad-marne).

Comment: I followed your updated answer, the build still failed. same error as before.